# Deploy simple asp.net webservice to azure

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, azure, servicestack

I am new to Azure so I just wanted to try out some things.

I created a simple webservice using ServiceStack that works just fine locally. I deployed it as a website to azure using Visual Studio 2012 publisher (right click project/Publish). Visual Studio says it was succesfully deployed, but when I go to my website url I can still see the default azure website.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happening a number of times. Mostly it is related to browser cache. Try clearing the browser cache or try with another browser. Other possibility could be the default document not set properly for your website, which can be done through Windows Azure Portal.

Comment: I also tried to access the webservice from a test console project and it couldn't find it. However, I tried again after one 30 minutes without changing anything at all, and it worked. I can also see it in my browser.